# ValueEventListener Not Called Inside ChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a ChildEventListener to iterate through a list of children in a Firebase node. Each of those children is a child of another node, and I am trying to access them using a ValueEventListener inside of my ChildEventListener. The ValueEventListener won't call at all. I have a print statement in the onDataChange method and it doesn't print.

```
 databaseReference.addOnChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

         databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("PRINT");
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

         });
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
 });
```

Theres more to databaseReference before I call the addOnChild... or addListener... but I don't know why it won't print the statement.

Comment: The most logical reason is that there are no child nodes under the location referenced by `databaseReference`, or that you don't have permission to read those children. See [this page on how to detect the latter](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201703140317445408).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know, but there are children and I do have access to them so I have no Idea what is going on.

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger, do you get into `onChildAdded()`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yep I can use onChildAdded()

Comment: Is `addOnChildEventListener` a method you defined?  The Firebase method is named `addChildEventListener`.